# Angular: ngOptions not displaying selected ng-model value

Tags: angularjs

I can't seem to figure out why `ng-options` and `ng-model` aren't working correctly within `<select>`: selected value `name` isn't being shown, although the `code` in the `element` object is correct...

Here are my objects:

```
$scope.hierarchyWorkElements = [];
$scope.worksToBeExecuted = [
 {
  id: 1,
  name: "Create Address Point"
 },
 {
  id: 2,
  name: "Create Segment"
 }
];
```

One object example from `$scope.hierarchyWorkElements` array:

```
$$hashKey: "07H",
code: "0",
id: "element1",
name: ""
```

And here is the `HTML`:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="element in hierarchyWorkElements" class="row top-buffer">
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <select class="form-control"
       ng-model="element.code"
       ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in worksToBeExecuted"></select>
  </div>
</div
```

Thanks in advance and kind regards!

Comment: There is no need to add attribute type="text" with select input directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your `ng-model` is not working as expected is `element.code` is a string where as `item.id` is an integer.You can either change your JSON objects  or try the below code.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.worksToBeExecuted = [{
        id: 1,
        name: "Create Address Point"
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: "Create Segment"
    }];
    $scope.hierarchyWorkElements = [{
        $$hashKey: "07H",
        code: "1",
        id: "element1",
        name: ""
    }, {
        $$hashKey: "09H",
        code: "2",
        id: "element2",
        name: ""
    }];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<htmL>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<div data-ng-repeat="element in hierarchyWorkElements" class="row top-buffer">
    <select class="form-control"
       ng-model="element.code"
       ng-options="item.id.toString() as item.name for item in worksToBeExecuted"></select>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're having ng-model as code property in array of objects inside hierarchyWorkElements & that is the value as id property in worksToBeExecuted. Type is different here, one is string & other number that should be fixed. Then you can track by $index to ng-repeat & actually see of all the select elements's model values with $scope.hierarchyWorkElements[index].code 
Also, here I'm assuming the hierarchyWorkElements array is;

```
$scope.hierarchyWorkElements=[{
                                code: "0",
                                id: "element1",
                                name: ""
                              },
                              {
                                code: "1",
                                id: "element2",
                                name: ""
                              }];
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/5epqBlmvyaMHLo00eJoD?p=preview

This's the example which emulates your requirement showing initial & after change model values, view values of select dropdowns.